# How to: TFS Integration with Rational Quality Manager and Rational Requirement Composer

Tags: tfs, tfsintegrationplatform, ibm-jazz

I am working on an integration approach for integrating Rational (IBM Jazz) Quality Manager (RQM) and Requirement Composer (RRC) with TFS.

As the teams are moving from ClearCase to TFS, what we are looking at is still being able to manage the requirements in RRC and manage testing using RQM.

The flow will be something like:

1. Requirements are planned and detailed in RRC
2. Create work items in TFS connected to the Requirements in RRC
3. Create design and code using VS2010 and managing the version control in TFS
4. Creating test plans and test cases in RQM (connected to requirements in RRC)
5. Run test against builds in TFS
6. Publish test results in RQM against builds in TFS
7. Run reports in RRC, RQM and TFS that links up the items across the platforms.

I have started looking at TFS Integration platform. But shall like to have your guidance for an early resolution and better solution approach and how to achieve this.

**UPDATE:**

As I was not getting good response here, I put this on MSDN and I really got good response there. I am not deleting this post here, but give the link here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsintegration/thread/fcb20f89-6801-4ad1-8f46-3df68325ca8d

Please follow this.

Comment: You didn't manage to ask a single question. :)

Comment: @Garen: You meant something? Could not get what you are saying.

Comment: You gave some background info, the subject is a statement, and there are no explicit questions here.  That's probably why no one has responded.  You say ... "shall like to have your guidance" but on what, exactly?